# Using the same variable for updated values

Tags: c#, azure

I use quite a few Azure services in my app and many a times, I have to first read some data, then manipulate it and then update the database. See simple example below:

```
// Read students list
var students = await _myRepository.GetStudents();

// Manipulate the data
students.Add(student);

// Then update the database which returns an updated list of students
// See the two options below
```

I, sometimes, use the same variable to get updated values and it works fine. Question is, should I always assign updated values to a new variable?

```
// Option 1: Use the same variable for updated values
students = await _myRepository.UpdateStudents(students);

// Option 2: Use a new one
var updatedStudents = await _myRepository.UpdateStudents(students);
```

When I assign updated values to new a variable, many times, I end up with so many of them which kind of complicates the code.

Comment: code which ever is more understandable. In general. it's bad practice to re-use vars for different purposes, but depends on context.

Comment: I have the same feeling about reusing variables so whenever I do it, it doesn't feel right but if I don't reuse them, then I end up with so many variables which make the code look more complicated than it really is.

Comment: That's often a symptom of needing to break the code down into classes: single responsibility....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal experience I have a rule which I generally follow: If the variable may be needed later for logging, additional operations, etc then I use a new variable, but if the variable now holds an invalid state, such as the variable before being updated, then I reuse the variable.

I find that this usually produces the best code because you do not end up with a bunch of invalid state variables. These invalid variables can become confusing down the line, as you may have to constantly refer back to determine which ones have the valid current state.

There is no hard and fast rule for this though, and if you have a complicated process having multiple step variables can be beneficial, but in the end it depends on the complexity of the task and the need for step variables.

Comment: Max, I like your rule. Putting it as "variable that holds invalid state" is a good way to look at it and clarifies the decision making process.